# Rave-report beforeprint event memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, rave-reports

I have this code in the event "DatabandBeforePrint" :

```
self.visible := not ((dvMatCommesseLavorazione.asstring = 'TAGLIO TRONCATRICE')
  or (dvMatCommesseLavorazione.asstring = 'TAGLIO SEZIONATRICE')
  or (dvMatCommesseLavorazione.asstring = 'TAGLIO PANTOGRAFO') );
```

When I close the application, why do I get a "Memory leak" from madexcept.
[memory leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As24A.png)

Is there anyone that could explain me why this occurs?

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: In the list of memory leaks I found  the string-value that "Asstring" function 
of the dataviewfield return

Answer (score 0):

I think this occurs because Rave vs Delphi WideString issues. You can workaround it adding and filling a boolean or integer field according your business rule. Checking an integer or boolean field would avoid WideString comparison. I read somewhere that new versions of Rave does correct this issues.